# XSD validate key value elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following xml with subtype that has properties "name" and "type" and also a key valued properties.My question is how should I validate the properties element with XSD that it has the correct name of the keys (mask,interval,stream,useNetworkShare) and correct type of values - string in this case.

```
 <subtype name="testType" type="test">
        <properties>
          <property key="mask" value="*" />
           <property key="interval" value="10" />
           <property key="stream" value="UnsortedSequential" />
           <property key="useNetworkShare" value="false" />
        </properties>
     </subtype>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSD isn't really designed to handle this sort of "genericized" XML. One way to do it is to transform to a more direct representation:

```
<subtype>
   <mask>*</mask>
   <interval>10</interval>
   <stream>UnsortedSequential</stream>
   <useNetworkShare>false</useNetworkShare>
</subtype>
```

and then write a schema for that. To be frank, the kind of "generic" XML you are working with seems to be invented by people who forget that XML is already generic - you can choose any element and attribute names you like.